# System of two linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, parametric

Given this system of linear equations where ${a}$ is parameter.

\begin{align}ax + 18y &= 13a^2 - a
\\5x + (a - 1)y &= 15 \end{align}

For which value of $a$ The system will have infinitely many solutions?
Give me different ways to solve this problem.
Need guide not solutions. 
I want to solve myself.

Comment: Please show some work.

Comment: Many ways how to do this. One way is this: Multiply first equation by $5$ and multiply second by $a$ and then subtract. This allows you to find $y$. Can you try this?

Comment: Yes . It's a one way.  Any other?

Comment: Convert into a 2x3 matrix (last row being the independent terms of the equation). Triangulate and try to find values of a that give you a rank 1 matrix (but not an incompatible system!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the second equation we get
$$x=3-\frac{1}{5}(a-1)y$$ plugging this in the first one
$$a\left(3-\frac{1}{5}(a-1)y\right)+18y=13a^2-a$$
can you finish?
from here we get
$$y\left(18-\frac{1}{5}a(a-1)\right)=13a^2-4a$$
finally we obtain
$$a^2-a-90\ne 0$$ and
$$x=\frac{13a^3-14a^2+a-270}{a^2-a-90}$$
$$y=-\frac{5a(13a-4)}{a^2-a-90}$$

Comment: Yes. Great. Thanks

Comment: for your Control i have added the solution

Comment: I think we can write X and Y more simply.

Comment: By the way there is only one Natural value for a. e.i a = 10

Comment: you can try it, it can not simplified at all

Comment: No there is no need to solve for x and y.  Question is about a.. and For infinite solutions a²-a-90 should be equal to zero instead of non equal . Correct?